# Struts2: Error in package statement while using actionsupport class

Tags: java, struts2, action, package

[image]I am to to run a simple struts 2 project which runs fine earlier, but when i added the class ActionSupport it shows the error as attached.

It shows no error in importing the class file but it shows the error in the package statement.

jdk 1.8
Struts 2[image]

Comment: Does the code compile?

Comment: Thanks for you reply Roman

no it gives an error.

Moreover i found an error and the resolution, the issue lies with the eclipse version and the java version i am using the eclipse version is Indigo and the java version is 1.8 jdk, so it was giving an error in java.util.MAp$Entry class.

To resolve the same either i need to upgrade my Eclipse to Luna or later or reduced my java version to 1.6 in build path.

Comment: It doesn't make sense why adding `ActionSupport` class leads to error. Anyway a version mismatch error leads to errors like that. Always use the latest version of the software.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, i found the error and the resolution, the issue lies with the eclipse version and the java version. i am using eclipse version s Indigo and the java version is 1.8 jdk, so it was giving an error in java.util.Map$Entry class.

To resolve the same either i need to upgrade my Eclipse to Luna or later or reduced my java version to 1.6 in build path.